# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to split dataframe in equal samples and applying some function to calculate value of each sample if any sample value greater than 0.3 then in result dataframe i want to save filename

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Value':[-0.016,-0.006,0.003,-0.011,-0.036,-0.031,-0.014,-0.006,-0.01 ,-0.009,0.004,0.001,-0.012,-0.021,-0.008,0.001,-0.011,-0.01,-0.006,0.002,0.004],'Nmae':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})

x=pd.DataFrame([x.values.sqrt(np.mean(df2['Value']**2)) for x in np.array_split(df2, (len(df2)/10))])
```

getting this error

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

if someone have any other effective way to do this task

Comment: `np.sqrt` is a `numpy` function.  There isn't a `sqrt` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working version of your Code:

```
 res= [np.sqrt(np.mean((x.Value**2))) for x in np.array_split(df, (len(df)/10))]
```

An alternative way of approaching this with Pandas would be. You define a new column 'Split_variable' and use it to apply your calculations:

```
df.groupby('Split_variable')['Value'].apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(np.mean((x**2))))
```